# Dropdownlist not displayed in Django

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, view, model

I am trying to implement a dropdownlist from my models into an HTML using Django. The form is working perfectly, but the dropdownlist is not displayed, it only displays "languages:" but not a dropdownlist or any options.
Any ideas?

**add_page.html**

```html
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <br>
    <form method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button style="background-color:#F4EB16; color:blue" 
                class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add Page</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from main.models import Pages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class PagesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pages
        fields = ["title","language","content"]
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
#from django.forms import ModelForm
# Create your models here.
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
    ('english','ENGLISH'),
    ('spanish', 'SPANISH'),
    ('german','GERMAN'),
    ('french','FRENCH'),
    ('chinese','CHINESE'),
)

#Pages son entradas del diario
class Pages(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField("Published: ", default=datetime.now())
    language = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='english')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
#/pages/my_pages/add_page
@login_required
def add_page(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)          
            model_instance.author = request.user.username
            model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
            messages.success(request, f"New page created, thank you: {model_instance.author}")  
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('/')

    else:
        form = PagesForm()

        return render(request, "main/add_page.html", {'form': form})
```

I've got nothing else to say, but the editor wont let me edit unless I write more text...

Comment: Please also include your `views.py`

Comment: done it, thanks for ur answer

Comment: Try moving the definition of `LANGUAGE_CHOICES` inside your model and see if that works for you? I think the `ModelForm` tries to find the choices from you model...

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I just _copy-paste_ your code and everything works fine for me ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/YdKG0Gs)).

Comment: Now it works for me too, the moment I comment out the materialize css file ... I am confused. Why would that be a compatibility problem ?